# Java JSONObject returning null

Tags: java, json, tomcat

I have an InputStream `is` and this code:

```
JSONObject jo = new JSONObject();
jo.put("currentHomeId", is.readLong());
jo.put("homeId", is.readLong());

boolean isInClan = is.readBoolean();
if (isInClan) {
    jo.put("clanId", is.readLong());
    jo.put("clanBadge", is.readInt());
    jo.put("clanLevel", is.readInt());
}

JSONArray ja = new JSONArray();
ja.put(jo);

mainObj = new JSONObject();
mainObj.put("avatar", ja);
return mainObj.toString();
```

I have this returned like so:
`String obj = avatar();`

But there is a problem which is causing this to always return null. Why is this happening and how can I fix it?

Also I am doing this on a tomcat server as I am making a web API.

Here is my full code:

This is what is used to call the json stuff:

```
 public static String obj;
  ....
 InputStream myis = new ByteArrayInputStream(decryptedPayload);
 Avatar avatar = new Avatar(myis);
 obj = avatar.parseAvatar();
```

And this here is the Avatar class:

```
public class Avatar {
    private PacketInputStream is;
    private JSONObject mainObj;


    public Avatar(InputStream myis) throws IOException, JSONException{
        is = new PacketInputStream(myis);
        parseAvatar();
    }

    public String parseAvatar() throws IOException, JSONException{  
        is.readVarInt();

        JSONObject jo = new JSONObject();
        jo.put("currentHomeId", is.readLong());
        jo.put("homeId", is.readLong());

        boolean isInClan = is.readBoolean();
        if (isInClan) {
            jo.put("clanId", is.readLong());
            jo.put("clanName", is.readString());
            jo.put("clanBadge", is.readInt());
            jo.put("clanLevel", is.readInt());
        }

        is.skipBytes(53);
        jo.put("league", is.readInt());
        jo.put("clanCaslteLevel", (is.readInt() + 1));
        jo.put("maxCcTroops", is.readInt());
        is.readInt();
        jo.put("townHall", (is.readInt() + 1));
        jo.put("userName", is.readString());
        is.readInt();
        is.readInt();
        is.readInt();

        JSONArray ja = new JSONArray();
        ja.put(jo);
        mainObj = new JSONObject();
        mainObj.put("avatar", ja);

        return mainObj.toString();



    }

}
```

This is the code that I am using to display it on the web:

```
String obj = MessageManager.obj;
out.println("JSON: "+obj);
```

`MessageManager` is the class that calls the Avatar class.

Thank you for the help you can provide.

Comment: This is a non sequitor: `String obj = avatar()` as you did not show us this code, nor any of the web code.  Can you include this?

Comment: `InputStream` doesn't have `readLong()`, `readBoolean()` or `readInt()`. Also I don't see gson code. `JSONObject` and `JSONArray` are from `org.json`

Comment: @ManosNikolaidis I also have a custom PacketInputStream class which has that stuff.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen I've added my full code so you can understand it now

Comment: To ask the obvious, have you debugged your code to make sure the stream is in fact working correctly?

Comment: i tried printing it in it's own program that doesn't run on tomcat or a webserver and it works fine. The JSON prints in the Avatar class. How come I can't get it returned though?

Comment: What would be the correct way of getting the Json from the MessagManager class to the class which is displaying it? @TimBiegeleisen